# SEO - Display block anchor tag contains title and short desc vs. only title with js

Tags: javascript, css, seo

I'm using an display block hyperlink to make the whole line clickable like this, something similar can be seen on youtube links (video list on the right). I'm concerned because there is alot of text in anchor tag, beside title, there is also short desc and categories.

```
<style type="text/css">
a.listarticle {display:block}
a.listarticle .title {font-weight:bold} 
</style>

<a class="listarticle" href="url">
    <span class="title" title="Article Title"><strong>Article Title</strong></span>
    <br />
    <span class="desc">Article short description</span>
    <span class="categories">Music, Animals...</span>
</a>
```

Could this be a better solution? Now anchor contains only article title, and whole line is clickable via javascript - anchor still exists? I'm pretty confused about this. I like the first solution better, but i'm not sure if first solution would have negative impact on search engines because beside title, there are alot of other noisy words included.

```
<div onclick="window.location='url'">
    <a href="url">Article Title</a>
    <br />   
    <span class="desc">Article short description</span>
    <br />
    <span class="categories">Music, Animals...</span>
</div>
```

Comment: "other noisy words included", then why aren't you just linking the title?

Comment: Because i want the whole block to be clickable not only a title

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to involve JS. This should get what you need.

```
<div>
    <a href="url">
        <span class="title" title="Article Title"><strong>Article Title</strong></span>
        <br />
        <span class="desc">Article short description</span>
        <br />
        <span class="categories">Music, Animals...</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

You could even do away with the "<div>" element and "display: block" for anchors with a ".myBigLink" class.

(I would personally lose the "<br />"s but that's not what you asked.)

Comment: That answer is the same as my first solution in question. The point is to link only title (SEO thing) and be able to click on the whole block. Nevermind, my solution was to take desc and categories out of hyperlink, and position them absolutely. Not perfect because i could not have custom height blocks but tolerable